# How do i open multiple browsers or .exe in windows at same time?

Tags: windows

When I come to office in each morning, to get started I have to open eclipse, Mozilla, Outlook, etc.

Can I make script or an file which contains .exe path of above programs and
once I run it, it will open all of the applications I need?

Comment: You shut your computer down?!

Comment: Yes, you can create a script to do that.

Comment: @ jeffamaphone  may the script will contain only path of .exe contain on my pc, where,how can i do that?

Comment: All will be revealed when your question is moved to the correct site.  In the mean time, check out: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=5FB255FF-72DA-4B08-A504-1B10266CF72A&displaylang=en

Answer (score 6):

It is much simpler than a script: Just copy the shortcuts to the Startup Program folder.

It is located here on XP:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ProfileName\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

And here on Vista/Windows 7:

> C:\Users\ProfileName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

The easiest way to get to the folder is to go to Start (or the new Windows Button)>All Programs>Startup and right click and open. Copy any shortcuts for the programs you want to open there.

Answer (score 0):

4 years late, but just for the record...

AutoHotKey can not only open them, but position their windows around your screen(s) exactly how you want them as well.